# How to write an ASTM frame to medical intrement?

Tags: node.js

I am currently working on the ASTM protocol using node js, the problem is I can't send a message to the equipment correctly
for example, I want to send this msg:

```
let msg = "H|!~|||LISHOST|||||||P|LIS2-A2|20040318235959
P|1||12345677||AHMED!SARMOUM||20120112!4!Y|M|||||
O|1|SID_133||!!!CD|||20160510111238||||N||||WB
L|1|N"
```

The current target machine is SELECTRA and COBAS E411